# How does a Python custom comparator work?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have the following Python dict:

```
[(2, [3, 4, 5]), (3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), (4, [-1]), (10, [1, 2, 3])]
```

Now I want to sort them on the basis of sum of values of the values of dictionary, so for the first key the sum of values is 3+4+5=12.

I have written the following code that does the job:

```
def myComparator(a,b):
    print "Values(a,b): ",(a,b)
    sum_a=sum(a[1])
    sum_b=sum(b[1])
    print sum_a,sum_b
    print "Comparision Returns:",cmp(sum_a,sum_b)
    return cmp(sum_a,sum_b)

items.sort(myComparator)
print items
```

This is what the output that I get after running above:

```
Values(a,b):  ((3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), (2, [3, 4, 5]))
2 12
Comparision Returns: -1
Values(a,b):  ((4, [-1]), (3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
-1 2
Comparision Returns: -1
Values(a,b):  ((10, [1, 2, 3]), (4, [-1]))
6 -1
Comparision Returns: 1
Values(a,b):  ((10, [1, 2, 3]), (3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]))
6 2
Comparision Returns: 1
Values(a,b):  ((10, [1, 2, 3]), (2, [3, 4, 5]))
6 12
Comparision Returns: -1
[(4, [-1]), (3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), (10, [1, 2, 3]), (2, [3, 4, 5])]
```

Now I am unable to understand as to how the comparator is working, which two values are being passed and how many such comparisons would happen? Is it creating a sorted list of keys internally where it keeps track of each comparison made? Also the behavior seems to be very random. I am confused, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to sort a dictionary or a list? Dictionaries are unordered, meaning you cannot change their order. In your example you show a list of tuples. What are you trying to sort?

Comment: Note that although Python 2 supports passing a custom comparison function to `sort()`, Python 3 does not. The main reason being that it's far more efficient to use a custom key function instead, since the key function only needs to be called once for each list item, whereas the comparison function must be called for every comparison made. See the link in RussellLuo's answer for details.

Comment: here is similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327344/custom-compare-function-in-python3/49327441#49327441

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number and which comparisons are done is not documented and in fact, it can freely change from different implementations. The only guarantee is that if the comparison function makes sense the method will sort the list.

CPython uses the [Timsort algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) to sort lists, so what you see is the order in which that algorithm is performing the comparisons (if I'm not mistaken for very short lists Timsort just uses insertion sort)

Python is **not** keeping track of "keys". It just calls your comparison function every time a comparison is made. So your function can be called many more than `len(items)` times.

If you want to use keys you should use the `key` argument. In fact you could do:

```
items.sort(key=lambda x: sum(x[1]))
```

This will create the keys and then sort using the usual comparison operator on the keys. This is guaranteed to call the function passed by `key` only `len(items)` times.

---

Given that your list is:

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

The sequence of comparisons you are seeing is:

```
b < a   # -1  true   --> [b, a, c, d]
c < b   # -1  true   --> [c, b, a, d]
d < c   # 1   false
d < b   # 1   false
d < a   # -1  true   --> [c, b, d, a]
```

Answer (score 2):

> how the comparator is working

This is well [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#cmp):

> Compare the two objects x and y and return an integer according to the outcome. The return value is negative if x < y, zero if x == y and strictly positive if x > y.

Instead of calling the cmp function you could have written:

```
sum_a=sum(a[1])
sum_b=sum(b[1])
if sum_a < sum_b: 
   return -1
elif sum_a == sum_b:
   return 0
else:
   return 1
```

> which two values are being passed

From your print statements you can see the two values that are passed. Let's look at the first iteration:

`((3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), (2, [3, 4, 5]))`

What you are printing here is a tuple (a, b), so the actual values passed into your comparison functions are

```
a = (3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1])
b = (2, [3, 4, 5]))
```

By means of your function, you then compare the sum of the two lists in each tuple, which you denote sum_a and sum_b in your code.

> and how many such comparisons would happen?

I guess what you are really asking: How does the sort work, by just calling a single function?

The short answer is: it uses the [Timsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm, and it calls the comparison function O(n * log n) times (note that the actual number of calls is c * n * log n, where c > 0).

To understand what is happening, picture yourself sorting a list of values, say `v = [4,2,6,3]`. If you go about this systematically, you might do this:

1. start at the first value, at index i = 0
2. compare v[i] with v[i+1]
3. If v[i+1] < v[i], swap them
4. increase i, repeat from 2 until i == len(v) - 2
5. start at 1 until no further swaps occurred

So you get, i =

```
0: 2 < 4 => [2, 4, 6, 3] (swap)
1: 6 < 4 => [2, 4, 6, 3] (no swap)
2: 3 < 6 => [2, 4, 3, 6] (swap)
```

Start again:

```
0: 4 < 2 => [2, 4, 3, 6] (no swap)
1: 3 < 4 => [2, 3, 4, 6] (swap)
2: 6 < 4 => [2, 3, 4, 6] (no swap)
```

Start again - there will be no further swaps, so stop. Your list is sorted. In this example we have run through the list 3 times, and there were 3 * 3 = 9 comparisons.

Obviously this is not very efficient -- the `sort()` method only calls your comparator function 5 times. The reason is that it employs a more efficient sort algorithm than the simple one explained above.

> Also the behavior seems to be very random.

Note that the sequence of values passed to your comparator function is not, in general, defined. However, the sort function does all the necessary comparisons between any two values of the iterable it receives.

> Is it creating a sorted list of keys internally where it keeps track of each comparison made?

No, it is not keeping a list of keys internally. Rather the sorting algorithm essentially iterates over the list you give it. In fact it builds subsets of lists to avoid doing too many comparisons - there is a nice visualization of how the sorting algorithm works at [Visualising Sorting Algorithms: Python's timsort](http://corte.si/%2Fposts/code/timsort/index.html) by [Aldo Cortesi](https://twitter.com/cortesi)

Comment: Thanks for a superb step by step pass through a comparator working on a sample list. +1.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for the simple list such as [2, 4, 6, 3, 1] and the complex list you provided, the sorting algorithms are the same.

The only differences are the complexity of elements in the list and the comparing scheme that how to compare any tow elements (e.g. `myComparator` you provided).

There is a good description for Python Sorting: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting

Answer (score 0):

First, the cmp() function:

```
cmp(...)
    cmp(x, y) -> integer
    Return negative if x<y, zero if x==y, positive if x>y.
```

You are using this line: `items.sort(myComparator)` which is equivalent to saying: `items.sort(-1)` or `items.sort(0)` or `items.sort(1)`

Since you want to sort based on the sum of each tuples list, you could do this:

```
mylist = [(2, [3, 4, 5]), (3, [1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), (4, [-1]), (10, [1, 2, 3])]
sorted(mylist, key=lambda pair: sum(pair[1]))
```

What this is doing is, I think, exactly what you wanted. Sorting `mylist` based on the `sum()` of each tuples list