# Custom compare function in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to sort points in 2D coordinate system by their distance to the origin (0,0) in increasing order. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531952/how-to-use-a-custom-comparison-function-in-python-3) and tried something, but still I could not get desired result.

Here is my code:

```
from functools import cmp_to_key

def my_comp(point1, point2):
    return point1[0]*point1[0] + point1[1]*point1[1] < point2[0]*point2[0] + point2[1]*point2[1]

points = [ [3.1, 4.1], [0.9, 0.8], [1.0, 1.0] ]
sorted(points, key=cmp_to_key(my_comp))
print(points)
```

Result:

```
[[3.1, 4.1], [0.9, 0.8], [1.0, 1.0]]
```

Expected:

```
[[0.9, 0.8], [1.0, 1.0], [3.1, 4.1]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Your `my_cmp()` function is supposed to return one of three values (+, -, or 0 depending upon the compare), but you only return two (True and False).

2) You ingnore the return value from `sorted()`. `sorted()` doesn't modify its argument, it returns a sorted copy of it.

3) Don't use cmp functions. They are hard to describe and hard to implement. Instead use key functions.

How about:

```
def my_key(point1):
    return point1[0]*point1[0] + point1[1]*point1[1]

points = [ [3.1, 4.1], [0.9, 0.8], [1.0, 1.0] ]
points = sorted(points, key=my_key)
print(points)

assert points == [ [0.9, 0.8], [1.0, 1.0], [3.1, 4.1] ]
```

Comment: Sir, I was missing the main point of sorted function, the one you mentioned in your 2nd improvement. It doesnt modify, it returns. Tnx.

Answer (score 4):

Does this do what you want?

```
sorted_points = sorted(points, key=lambda p: p[0]*p[0] + p[1]*p[1])
```

Another thing to watch out for in your original code is that sorted does not sort the list in place, it creates a new list that is sorted. So when you do

```
points = [3,2,1]
sorted(points)
print(points)
```

It will appear that your code hasn't sorted anything because you are printing the original list not the newly created sorted one. You can perform a sort in place like so.

```
points = [3,2,1]
points.sort()
print(points)
```

Comment: There's no need to take the square root. Remove the import and speed things up.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are going through some extra hoops here. You have a quantity that is already a perfect key. Instead of just using it, you define a comparator that recomputes and compares two of these quantities for every pair of objects, and then convert that comparator back to a key.

This seems very inefficient. Why not just define a simple key function and use it directly?

```
def distance_from_origin_squared(point):
    return point[0]**2 + point[1]**2
points = sorted(points, key=distance_from_origin_squared)
```

Keep in mind that `sorted` does not operate in-place, so you have to stash it somewhere. Replacing the original name if fine. If you want an in-place sort, use `list.sort` instead:

```
points.sort(key=distance_from_origin_squared)
```

From a practical point of view, keys offer a number of advantages over comparators. For one thing, a key function only needs to be called once per element, while a comparator is called `O(nlog(n))` times. Of course the keys are compared `O(nlog(n))` times, but the comparison is usually much simpler since the values of interest are computed up front.

The main difficulty coming from C (in my case) is grasping the idea that keys do not have to be single integers, as is usually shown in examples. Keys can be **any** type that clearly defines the `<` (or `>`) operator. Lexicographical comparison of strings, lists and tuples makes it very easy to boil a complex chained comparator to a key that is just a short sequence of values.

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing the `cmp` and `key` arguments.  A `cmp` function accepts two arguments and returns `-1`, `0`, or `1`.  A `key` function returns a proxy value that will be used to sort the list. `cmp` was removed as an argument to `sorted` in Python 3.

Comment: Ok, but shouldn't `cmp_to_key` still work regardless of whether the `cmp` keyword exists?

Comment: @Kevin It would, except that a `cmp` function is still supposed to return -1.0,1, not True/False

Comment: @BrendanAbel. True. It's supposed to return True, False and -1 :) Technically True == 1 and False == 0. bools are a subclass of int.

Comment: Also, it's not just +/-1. Any positive or negative value will do.